# Not able to get response from the Java application using the "request" in ReactJS app, however API is working fine with postman

Tags: java, reactjs, request, postman

I copied postman code and try to run it from the ReactJS app but it is giving error "Uncaught Error: Error: Invalid URI "/dologin"
I also used setupProxy.js file in the reactjs app but it is not working.

Here is my code from Postman.

var request = require("request");

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://x.x.x.x:8080/dologin',
    headers: {
        'postman-token': 'b8754e2-974a-98fc-08e8-d40215dd226c',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YW21547gW'
    },
    formData: {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

```
console.log(body);
```

});

If I remove CORS from the server then I am able to get the response but token is not coming in the header, however it is coming if I use Postman.

Please help, thanks

Comment: You should use fetch instead of request

Comment: I have already tried fetch, axios but nothing worked. If i use same code for jsonplaceholder.com, i am able to get response but it is not working with spring boot app